# Complete Online Form Query And Store Result In Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I hoping to develop a simple database to store the results of OFAC searches in an Access database.  The steps that I'm hoping to achieve follow:

1. Enter company name in Access form
2. Execute query (via clicking a button or otherwise)
3. Goto OFAC website ([OFAC Website](https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/))
4. Enter Company name in Name Field
5. Execute a search by clicking Search button or hitting return.
6. Receive the result set and Store in Access table

Questions:

1. Can I accomplish these steps with Access
2. Are you aware of any resources (articles, Access add-ins, VBA Scripts) that can help me achieve these objectives

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. OFAC provides access to data using web service API, which can be called using VBA. I didn't use VBA for accessing OFAC, but used with other web services. Search string "ofac list api" gives a lot of links, for instance [here](http://www.xignite.com/product/OFAC-data/api/GetCriteria/) you can find code example for VB6, it's similar to VBA, may be useful.